# How to nest v-show and v-if together in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

For Example,
the web app will follow the following steps:

• It reads a name from the user, and displays back a message.

• Check if the name entered is your name.

• If the name is your name, output the message 'Awesome name!'

• Otherwise output the ‘not my name’ message.

**How this can be achieved with v-show and v-if in Vue.js?**

Below is the sample code, Hence, How to use v-show, so that the v-if is only showed when condition is met?

```
    <!-- Show if str is vue-->
    <p v-if="strName.toLowerCase() == 'henil'">Awesome Name!</p>
    <!-- else -->
    <p v-else>{{ strName }} is not my name!</p>
    </div>
    
    <!-- All Bootstrap plug-ins file -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    
    <!-- All VueJS -->
    <script src="js/vue.min.js"></script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //assigning variables
    var strName = '';
    //creating new Vue instance
    new Vue({
        el: '#app', //denotes where vue js app starts
        data:  {strName}//passing variables into vue app
    });
```

[I am getting this output with above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SQhL.png)

Comment: Can you provide what you've tried so far and isn't working?

Comment: Working fine for me. What issue you are facing ?

Comment: right now, I'm getting both 'Awesome name' and 'is not my name!' on the webpage. (See the image attached in question). However, I'm only supposed to get any output shown if the any of the condition is met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like vue.js is not loaded on the dom, you must use a div with an id of app in your html

E.g：

```
<div id="app">
    <input v-model="strName">
    <p v-if="strName.toLowerCase() == 'henil'">Awesome Name!</p>
    <p v-else>{{ strName }} is not my name!</p>
</div>
```

OR

It may be that your code is not running on the web server, and you directly use the browser to open the local file, causing vue.js to not run.

Comment: Hi, even after adding the ID, I'm still getting the same output (image attached with the original question). the 'Awesome name!' is only supposed to show up after getting user's input.

Comment: It may be that your code is not running on the web server, and you directly use the browser to open the local file, causing vue.js to not run.